# How to check if an element of an array is the same as any of the previous elements

Tags: java, arrays, list

This is some of my code for a game I am currently working on.

```
public void compareGuess() {
    black = 0;
    white = 0;
    List<String> previousBoard;
    for (i=0; i<numColours; i++) {
        if(Arrays.asList(mySecret).contains(Board[row][i])) {
            if (Board[row][i].equals(mySecret[i])) {
                black = black + 1;
            } else {
                for (int j=i-1; j>=0; j--) {
                    previousBoard = Arrays.asList(Board[row][j]);
                }
                if (!Board[row][i].contains(previousBoard)) {
                    white = white + 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am only having difficulties with the for statement which comes straight after the else. I basically need to check if the element I am currently on `Board[row][i]` contains any of the previous elements so `Board[row][i-1]`, `Board[row][i-2]` and so on, if it doesn't, then I need to increment white by 1.

However when I run this I get the error:

```
incompatible types: List<String> cannot be converted to CharSequence
```

Is there any way around this?

Comment: What type is `Board`? Is it a `String[][]`?

Comment: Yes, basically I just need a method to check if Board[row][i] equals to any of the previous elements, so Board[row][i-1->0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you just want to replace

```
!Board[row][i].contains(previousBoard)
```

with

```
!previousBoard.contains(Board[row][i])
```

This checks to see if the `Board[row][i]` is equal to one of the previous elements. I know you said you wanted to check if "Board[row][i] contains any of the previous elements" but `Board[row][i]` is a String so I think you meant that you want to check if `Board[row][i]` is in the set of previous elements.

Additionally, I believe based on your intended functionality that the line

```
previousBoard = Arrays.asList(Board[row][j]);
```

is incorrect. You want to **concatenate** the list to the `previousBoard`. So you should use

```
previousBoard.addAll(Arrays.asList(Board[row][j]));
```

and initialize the `previousBoard` variable above the add statement with

```
List<String> previousBoard = new LinkedList<>();
```

Comment: That was exactly my issue, sorry I didn't explain my problem correctly. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a sub array and test in each step the existens:

1)

```
Arrays.copyOfRange(Object[] src, int from, int to)
```

2)

```
Arrays.asList(someArray).contains(value);
```

In my eyes you can create a second array, in each step you check existens and add the new value to second array.

Comment: In 1) can I use String[][] instead of an object. I only need to test one line of a 2D array with it self.